# Pylons and Facebook?

Tags: facebook, pylons

I'm looking for a good example / explanation for allowing logging in to my pylons website with facebook (oauth 2.0). I need to read the user's email and therefore need him to login with facebook to my pylons website. If anyone can point me out to how this is done, I would be very happy - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I published [this post](http://wuilly.com/?p=148) covering oauth 2.0, I hope it helps.